# request-promise и request ? Нужен поток, но ответ с сервера нужно ждать

Tags: node.js, request, fstream

Я делаю запрос на сервер, и он отвечает через 30 мин JSON строкой, которую я потом разбираю в потоке.

Но у меня такая проблема.

Что бы дождаться ответа с сервера, мне необходимо использовать 'request-promise'.

А чтобы сделать поток то 'request'.

Поэтому если я жду ответ, то PIPE не работает. А если использовать 'request', то запрос не висит(не ждет 30 мин) и выкидавается ошибка.

**Вот нерабочий код**
(т.к. 'request-promise' не поддерживает .pipe() )
       var rp = require('request-promise');

```
   rp(opt)
.then( response => {
    response
    .pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
     return data}))
});
```

**Рабочий код** ( НО только если response моментальный. А мне нужно чтобы он ждал 30 мин ответа ) :

```
    request(opt)
      .pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
      .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
          console.error(data)
        return data
      }))
```

Comment: не уверен, что правильно понял Ваш вопрос, но если вам надо распарсить json, то попробуйте вот так: .then( response => {var data = JSON.parse(response."какое-то поле"); console.log(data); return data; });

Comment: @muturgan. Нет, через JSON.parse не получится, потому что очень большая строка. Нужно парсить потоками

Comment: Мне нужно как то добиться того, что бы при request не выкидывалась ошибка, а дожидалось ответа.

Comment: надо же, даже не знал что JSON.parse имеет ограничение по длине строки

Comment: никогда не пользовался указанными пакетами. но. если я правильно понимаю - вам не нужно использовать pipe с rp так как в объекте response уже есть все необходимые данные, которые rp получил под капотом с помощью потоков. вам остается эти данные только использовать. выведите response в консоль и посмотрите что там есть

Comment: собственно просто почитайте документацию к модулю request-promise на сайте npm. там все понятно написано